# More than one kind of profile with spring

Tags: java, spring

I work with spring profiles with several configurations (prod, dev, test ...). I'm using several property files such as "application-prod.properties", "application-dev.properties ...). At this point, everything's fine.

But now, I want to add a language management using the same system. I tried to add 2 languages, english and french. So I created 2 more property files : "application-fr.properties" and "application-en.properties". Then I tag main main language configuration class with :

```
    @Profile({ "fr", "en"})
    public class MyClass{
        public static String MYVAR;

        @Value("${myclass.myvar}")
        private void setMyVar(String myVar) {
            MYVAR = myVar;
        }
    }
```

With my config files being like :

```
myclass.myvar=...
```

My active dev profile is "dev,en" for example, and it doesn't set my vars.

Any idea how to fix my issue ?

Comment: how are you setting your active profiles

Comment: Editing the spring.profiles

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue, my syntax was ok, it was an ordering problem with my class constructions. My config file was initialized too late.